# Android Device unrecognized LG G3

Tags: android, android-emulator, device, detect, lg

I just bought an Android phone : the LG G3 , to use it as emulator and therefore test my applications. However, it is not recognized by Android Studio: yet I enabled USB debugging ( I activated devellopeur mode) and allowed unknown sources but it does not work.
My phone is yet recognized by my computer but not on Android Studio!

Thank you for your help !:

Comment: btw, you do not use a device AS an emulator but AS a device, Android Studio will show up the device as a "device"

Answer (score 6):

This are the steps that worked for me:

1. Unplug your phone from the computer
2. Make yourself a "developer" on your phone. Settings > General > About phone > Software information ... then tap "Build number" a bunch of times until it says "You are now a developer" or something like that.
3. Go into the developer settings ... Settings > General > Developer options
4. Check "USB Debugging"
5. Plug the phone in to your computer
6. Drop down the notifications menu and click on the item that has the subtitle "Tap for more USB options". Most likely, the main title will say "Media Device (MTP)". Anyway - click on that.
7. Then choose the option "Send Images (PTP)"

More details [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-connecting-lg-g3-to-linux-adb-aka-t2821673).

Answer (score 2):

You have to **download and install LG G3 driver since** you are on Windows.

Drive can be found on LG Website : [direct link](http://tool.xcdn.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425), [source](http://www.lg.com/fr/support-mobile/lg-G3)

Install it, plu you're device once it's installed and it's will be ok.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks for linking the DL.